# Assigning values to array of pointers in Fortran

Tags: arrays, pointers, fortran

I would like to assign values to array of pointers in Fortran 2003. Array of pointers is realised by means of a derived data type `arrpntr`. Please take a look at a simple example below:

```
  PROGRAM TST_PNTR

  real, allocatable, target  :: arr1(:), arr2(:)

  ! array of pointers
  type :: arrpntr
    real, pointer :: arr(:) => null()
  end type

  type(arrpntr) :: p(2)

  integer :: err

  integer, parameter :: M = 10, N = 10

  allocate(arr1(M), arr2(N), stat=err)

  arr1 = [ (i, i=1, 10) ]
  arr2 = arr1**2

  ! arr1 = arr1-0.5
  ! p(1)%arr => arr1

  p(1)%arr => arr1-0.5
  p(2)%arr => arr2

  write(*,*) p(1)%arr
  write(*,*) p(2)%arr

  arr1 = arr1**2
  arr2 = sqrt(arr2)

  write(*,*) p(1)%arr
  write(*,*) p(2)%arr

  deallocate(arr1, arr2, stat=err)

  nullify(p(1)%arr, p(2)%arr)

  END PROGRAM TST_PNTR
```

In its current state compiler throws an error: `Pointer assignment target is neither TARGET nor POINTER at (1)` complaining about the line `p(1)%arr => arr1-0.5`. It works in case I split the operation into two parts as in the commented lines above. However, I would like to achieve the same result without storing an intermediate result in a temporary variable `arr1`. Operation `arr1-0.5` is a simple example. In reality I would like to use a much more complex expression on the right hand side of `p(1)%arr =>`. Is there a better way avoiding the use of an intermediate array?

Comment: What is it you really want to do?  One can't point to arbitrary expressions, but I don't see why you prefer pointers in this case rather than, say, a normal array.

Comment: *I would like to assign values to array of pointers*  Like the compiler tells you, you can't.  If the *rhs* of `p(1)%arr => arr1-0.5` isn't stored what do you expect to point to ?

Comment: My _rhs_ is an array of finite differences of the type `arr(imin:imax)-arr(imin-1:imax-1)`, where `arr` changes with every outer loop iteration. I was looking into pointers since the first 1d array in the derived data type `arrpntr` didn't need an explicit copy and I could get away with a pointer.

Comment: You may use allocatables...

Comment: *In reality ...*  Surely.  But in reality even an expression such as `arr(imin:imax)-arr(imin-1:imax-1)` may prompt your compiler to create (and destroy) temporary array behind the scenes, more complex expressions are more likely to cause that.  Are you trying to economise on memory usage ?  Are you trying to economise on the number of lines of code you write ?

Comment: This is what I suspected. I'm trying to save the memory.

Comment: What you are trying with `p(1)%arr => arr1-0.5` is absolute nonsense in any traditional  programming language I know (with traditional pointers). You can only point to some memory location. (Let's ignore that one could imagine a reference to a temporary which could get garbage collected by something later.) I think it would be easier to come up with a question about the best way to treat your actual algorithm.

Comment: It seems to me like you want to recalculate the result `(arr1-0.5)` dynamically to save memory at the cost of speed. I think you should be using a function instead.

Comment: Perhaps this is stating the obvious, but if you want to assign a value, you use "normal" assignment (`=`).  Pointer assignment (`=>`) is used when you want to point a pointer at something else.  If you do assign a value to a pointer, you first need to make sure that the pointer is pointing at something that can be assigned to.